# iOS5 Twitter Integration: How to add custom text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

I have implemented the Twitter-framework and it lets users tweet posts from within the app correctly. However, I would like to add some text at the end of every tweet a user sends from within the app. Example:

Tweet: Oh this app is so extremely awesome!! - via @AccountOfMyAppCompany

I want the last part '- via @Acc...' to be added to each tweet, and in such a way the user can't delete or customize it. I've tried fooling around a bit with `AddURL`, but that (obviously) lets you only add URLs, and no custom text. Also, `setInitialText` doesn't do as this sets text at the beginning of the tweet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The name of your application [will already be shown after the tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios-frequently-asked-questions#Why_is_my_application_attributed_as_from_iOS_instead_of_from_my_application_on_twitter.com) on twitter.com.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend adding text to tweets unless the user is ok with that.

You don't have to use the new Twitter compose view controller. Look at the apple twitter example code, it has a method to send a tweet directly.

You could implement your own custom input field and have your 'required' text greyed out but visible to the user and then send it all directly.
Various examples around of how to capture user input whilst indicating the character count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are proposing. The documentation on the Twitter Framework is quite clear :

***"Although you may perform Twitter requests on behalf of the user, you cannot append text, images, or URLs to tweets without the user’s knowledge. Hence, you can set the initial text and other content before presenting the tweet to the user but cannot change the tweet after the user views it"***